# Проблема с языком нотификаций в Django

Tags: python-3.x, django

столкнулся с проблемой языком нотификаций, именно у форм. В setting.py язык стоит en `LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'`
но при нажатие на submit в форме(когда поле пустое и заданно, что оно обязательное) выскакивает оповещение -  "Пожалуйста, заполните это поле" на русском языке (и так по всему сайту). Как можно исправить это?

Comment: Это выставляется в настройках браузера, а не в джанге

Comment: @andreymal да, помогло

Answer (score 0):

Помогла смена языка в браузере!